# Unable to point the child theme directory even using get_stylesheet_directory()

Tags: functions, child-theme, include

I am developing a child theme based on **storefront** as parent theme. I am trying to include files in child theme `functions.php` file as:

```
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/_customizer.php';
require_once get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/_header.php';
```

When I move any function from `functions.php` file to `_header.php` or `_cuztomizer.php` files which are in the `inc` folder in the child theme it does't works but either in `functions.php` file it works very well. I don't know what I am doing wrong and how I can include files in `function.php` file.

Please help me. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26414230/how-to-allow-require-once-to-php-file-in-wordpress) state that `require_once` operates at a file-system level. I would try

`include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/_customizer.php';`

try to change `require_once` with `include` and see if that works. If it does, you can research how to use `require_once` correctly at your leisure.

Comment: Thanks bro.it works as `include get_stylesheet_directory() . '/inc/_header.php'`;